# Error maximum execution time exceeded en XAMPP

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, xampp

Estoy tratando de importar una base de datos en phpmyadmin, pero me da el siguiente error.

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 300 seconds exceeded in C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\vendor\phpmyadmin\sql-parser\src\Lexer.php on line 805

Cabe aclarar que probé modificando el valor $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'], pero luego me aparece una página en blanco en phpmyadmin y tuve que volver a reinstalar todo.

Comment: Tienes que cambiar el php.ini y reiniciar el servicio de apache. Es más estoy justo en eso yo. max_execution_time = 60 ;
max_input_time = 90 ;
memory_limit = 128M ;
upload_max_filesize = 200M ;
post_max_size = 180M ;

El archivo lo encuentras en xampp/php/php.ini

Comment: Esas variables puedes revisar para una correcta ejecucion.